# Runtime panic when copying texture in SDL Go program

Tags: go, sdl, sdl-2

I have an SDL2 go program which tries to write a pixel array to the screen. When I try and update the texture with the new pixels the program panics with a runtime error:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
```

Unfortunately I can find little to no documentation about how to pass around unsafe pointers in Go and I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly, here is some example code that exhibits the problem:

```
func main() {
    window := sdl.CreateWindow("test", sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        800, 600, sdl.WINDOW_SHOWN)
    renderer := sdl.CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0)
    texture := sdl.CreateTexture(renderer, sdl.PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
        sdl.TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, 800, 600)

    defer renderer.Destroy()
    defer texture.Destroy()
    defer window.Destroy()

    for {
        pixels := make([]uint32, 800*600)

        texture.Update(nil, unsafe.Pointer(&pixels), int(800*unsafe.Sizeof(pixels)))
        window.UpdateSurface()

        renderer.Clear()
        renderer.Copy(texture, nil, nil)
        renderer.Present()
    }

    sdl.Delay(1000)
    sdl.Quit()
}
```

This code will compile with no errors, but when ran it will produce a runtime panic, but I can't see what would cause that in this code.

I am using these SDL2 Go bindings: https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2

Comment: the bug is in `texture.Update(nil, unsafe.Pointer(&pixels), int(800*unsafe.Sizeof(pixels)))`, changing it to `texture.Update(nil, unsafe.Pointer(&pixels), 0)` makes it run, but I don't know enough about sdl to diagnose the actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pitch parameter expects the surface's width * sizeof(int32) as far as I can, this code works and prints random pixels every loop:

```
func main() {
    window, err := sdl.CreateWindow("test", sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        sdl.WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600, sdl.WINDOW_SHOWN)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer window.Destroy()

    renderer, err := sdl.CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer renderer.Destroy()

    texture, err := renderer.CreateTexture(sdl.PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
        sdl.TEXTUREACCESS_STATIC, 800, 600)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer texture.Destroy()

    pixels := make([]uint32, 800*600)
L:
    for {
        for event := sdl.PollEvent(); event != nil; event = sdl.PollEvent() {
            if _, ok := event.(*sdl.QuitEvent); ok {
                break L
            }
        }
        for i := range pixels {
            pixels[i] = 0x00777777 + uint32(rand.Intn(0x00AAAAAA))
        }
        //4 == sizeof(int32), unsafe.Sizeof(pixels) returns the actual size of
        //the slice header which is 24
        texture.Update(nil, unsafe.Pointer(&pixels[0]), 800*4)
        window.UpdateSurface()

        renderer.Clear()
        renderer.Copy(texture, nil, nil)
        renderer.Present()
    }

    sdl.Delay(1000)
    sdl.Quit()
}
```

//edit it should be `unsafe.Pointer(&pixels[0])` not `unsafe.Pointer(&pixels)`.

Comment: This works thanks, I had a feeling that this was what was wrong from the comment on my question. Strangely though I now get a solid black band near the top of the window as seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yefx9x1mtoxck3j/Screenshot%202014-08-15%2013.56.21.png). This seems like a different issue though, so I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @JoeBentley I got that too, but I'm not quiet sure why, you *might* have to use a surface but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Please don't ignore `error` returns! It's bad practice and even worse practice to do such things in "example" code that others may follow. Sadly the small edit to the answer to just `log.Fatal` errors was rejected.

Comment: @DaveC not sure who rejected it, however you are absolutely correct, I added the error checking code.